# Why Subject subscribe is not working in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subject

I have a Subject defined in the authentication service. When I want to move user information to another component, subscribe doesn't work and it doesn't work. I tried to use it in different hooks, but again it was useless. I also used BehaviorSubject, but null returns.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

auth.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthModel} from '../Infrastructure/Models/authModel';
import {RegisterUserDeviceModel} from '../Infrastructure/Models/RegisterUserDeviceModel';
import {ResponseModel} from '../Infrastructure/Models/responseModel';
import {RegisterUserDeviceResponseModel} from '../Infrastructure/Models/registerUserDeviceResponseModel';
import {LoginResponseModel} from '../Infrastructure/Models/LoginResponseModel';
import {RegisterDeviceDataMosel} from '../app.component';
import {BehaviorSubject, Subject, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {UserDataModel} from '../Infrastructure/Models/UserDataModel';
import {catchError, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {RoleEnum} from '../Infrastructure/Enums/RoleEnum';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    devicecode: string = (<RegisterDeviceDataMosel> JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('RegisterDeviceData'))).devicecode;
    user = new Subject<UserDataModel>();

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
}

Signin(data: AuthModel) {
    let _headers = new HttpHeaders();
    _headers = _headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    _headers = _headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    _headers = _headers.append('X-Skip-Interceptor', '');
    _headers = _headers.append('device_code', this.devicecode);
    const _options = {headers: _headers};

    return this._http.post<ResponseModel<LoginResponseModel>>('http://localhost:5000/account/login', data, _options)
        .pipe( catchError(this.handelError) , tap(resData => {
            this.handleAuth(data.username, resData.response.access_token, resData.response.refresh_token
                , resData.response.role, resData.response.expires_in);
        }));
}

AutoLoading(): boolean {
    debugger;
    const userData: {
        username: string,
        access_token: string,
        refresh_token: string,
        role: RoleEnum,
        _tokenexpirationDate: string
    } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    if (!userData) {
        return false;
    }
    const loadUser = new UserDataModel(userData.username, userData.access_token, userData.refresh_token
        , userData.role, new Date(userData._tokenexpirationDate));
    if (loadUser.token) {
        this.user.next(loadUser);
        return true;
    }
}

private handleAuth(username, token, refresh_token, role, expiresin) {
    const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + +expiresin * 60000);
    const user = new UserDataModel(username, token, refresh_token
        , role, expirationDate);
    debugger;
    this.user.next(user);
    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user));
}

private handelError(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse){
    return throwError(errorResponse);
}
}
```

component

```
import {AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as momenthijri from 'moment-hijri';
import {AuthService} from '../../auth/auth.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  providers: [AuthService]
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy {
  private userSub: Subscription ;
  nowDate = new Date();
  hijri;
  public userName;
  public role;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hijri = momenthijri(this.nowDate.toString()).format('iYYYY/iM/iD');
    this.userSub = this.authService.user.subscribe( res =>{
      debugger;
      this.userName = res.username ;
      this.role = res.role;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.userSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: is it going inside your handleAuth Method? try putting console log in that method?

Comment: yes . That method works .

Comment: Try printing user object before calling next?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `Subject` doesn't store the data inside and you have to subscribe **before** providing the data in your subject. Also, you can use `BehaviorSubject` that stores the data inside, and all the time you subscribe to it you will receive this data, but you have to provide an initial value.

On the other hand, you can simulate `BehaviorSubject` without initial value by `user = new ReplaySubject<UserDataModel>(1)` which will store the last data and return it every time you subscribe. Hope, my explanations is clear :)

Comment: thanks for your response . I null the initial values of the BehaviorSubject. This side was entered but the null value was entered into the subscribe. What's the problem ؟

Comment: You need to call `AutoLoading` or `Signin` and only after that you will receive the user. But be careful, when you call `AutoLoading` you have to be sure that in local storage will be `loadUser.token` due to if condition in this method. Also when you call `Signin` you have to wait until your post method will get a response.